# Django throwing "CSRF token missing or incorrect" Error (because of empty value of csrfmiddlewaretoken)

Tags: python, django, cookies, csrf

I recently got stuck with a pretty strange issue. I have a form in my template as follows:

```
<form class="form" id="loginForm" role="form" action="/user/login/" 
  method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
     placeholder="Enter email" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password"
     name="password" placeholder="Password" value="">
</div>
<div class="cl-effect-7">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SIGN IN</button>
</div>
</form>
```

I was getting **`CSRF token missing or incorrect`**. Digging further deep down i found that though **csrftoken** cookie is getting correctly set in the browser the POST request is having empty value of **csrfmiddlewaretoken** and hence it throws the error with the said reason.

Also here is my view(though I doubt if there is anything wrong with it)

```
def user_login(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled.")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
    else:
        return render_to_response('user/login.html', {},context_instance = context)
```

Here's the other view which redirects to login.html:

```
def index(request):
    context_dict = {}
    template = "user/login.html" #default template to render
    user = None
    user_profile = None

    user = request.user.id
    if user != None:
        user_profile,created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

    #Check whether the user is new,if yes then he needs to select btw Mentor-Mentee
    if user_profile and user_profile.is_new:
        context_dict['selected'] = None
        template = "user/select.html" #User has to select either Mentor/Mentee,so redirect to select.html


    return render_to_response(template,context_dict,context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Now I used little JavaScript to get around this, by setting the value of csrfmiddlewaretoken from the cookie manually but that's a little strange behavior from Django.
PS: Im using **Django 1.7** and tested this on **all browsers.**

Comment: this might help http://codeureka.blogspot.in/2014/03/csrf-verification-failed-while-making.html

Comment: why do you set ``action`` if the same url and view handles the user login? are you trying to login from another view at first? in this case, maybe you are not passing the csrf token

Comment: Try clearing all cached cookies in the browser and restart the server. Also, I'm assuming you have a closing `</form>` tag that isn't shown in the code snippet, but if not you should add it.

Comment: @aus_lacy Noticed now, it was right there in the code snippet but stupid formatting must have eaten the tag. Corrected it now.

Comment: @MihaiZamfir checked the other view,tweaked it a bit, thought it was correct but it was my browser loading the old js script which had manual setting of csrfmiddlewaretoken. So problem still unsolved!

Comment: Try `return render_to_response('user/login.html', RequestContext(request, {})` for your `user_login` view. As well as `return render_to_response(template, RequestContext(request, context_dict))` for your `index` view.

Comment: @aus_lacy Nope! Still getting the same damn error. :|

Comment: have you cleared out your browser cache (delete cookies) as well as django's cache?  try changing your SECRET_KEY in settings.py as well after you clear the browsers cache.  Then close and reload the page.

Comment: Well if that didn't work then my last suggestion would similar to my first comment and @warath-coder's comment to completely delete the browser cache and then reload the page.

Answer (score -3):

Try adding this to your form:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
</div>
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#other-template-engines

Comment: No.. you should never add this yourself manually. The `csrf_token` template tag is doing that for you

Comment: I know, but @Anmol said that the token was empty, so forcing is a better workaround than using JS to fetch the token from the cookies.

Comment: Thanks but tried that already, didn't help :/.Also all other forms (in other templates) are working perfectly. So Django's middleware isn't goofing up anywhere for sure :p